# Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel aren't tracking all visits

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a customized pageviews counter at my website, so i compared it with Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel data, and i noted they aren't tracking all the visits. Actually, GA is counting a lot less visits. However, i didn't identified a pattern. As an example, for page A, my counter show 34,010 pageviews, while GA shows 2,757. For page B, my counter shows 21,690, while GA shows 8,994. Facebook Pixel is counting fewer pageviews than GA. I also have Facebook pagelike plugin at the website. Here is my related code:

```
<head>
...
        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-33363893-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <!-- End Google Analytics -->

        <!-- Facebook Pixel -->
        <script>
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
                n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
                n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
                t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
                document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

            fbq('init', '1552520671727240');
            fbq('track', "PageView");
            <?php
            $p = $controller . ' - ' . $action;
            switch($p){
                case 'usuario - cadastrado':
                    echo "fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');";
                break;
            }
            ?>
        </script>
        <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                   src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1552520671727240&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
            /></noscript>
        <!-- End Facebook Pixel -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1494091077554768";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No two trackers report exactly the same data. There are a number of reasons for this:

- Definitional questions around what does and doesn't constitute a Page View, Session or User.
- Different data aggregation methods; some platforms may induce sampling.
- The position of the tracker on the page makes a difference: a tracker at the top of the page will receive more than one at the bottom (although yours seem pretty close together here).
- Asynchronous code is used by some trackers and not others.
- Not all browsers allow JavaScript, some trackers respond to this better than others.
- Some people have blocking technology, which will likely notice some trackers and not others, and react differently to each (I believe Google has an understanding about Google Analytics and Ad Blocker).
- Many trackers have opt-outs that people can have enabled.
- Trackers often rely on cookies, which different people will have different settings for. Different trackers will use different types of cookies (3rd party vs 1st party) and some may rely on them more than others.
- Spiders, bots and referral spam can cause a small amount of traffic that certain trackers may choose to filter out.

You should definitely check your implementation of these trackers on both pages; I recommend using Google Tag Manager, correctly placed immediately after the opening  tag on each page, to deploy them all. This should make them give more similar results. However, you're never going to get the same numbers. You have to accept that each tracker does its own thing.

Comment: Thanks, @J Brazier! I have made a script to parse apache's access log today, eliminating bot's entries and other stuffs, and i see almost all the visits are from real users. I noted a huge difference in the number of visits i see in the logs compared with trackers numbers. As an example, a post I published yesterday have more than 5,000 real visits and more than 1,000 shares on Facebook, but Google Analytics shows only 60 pageviews. I'll try the Tag Manager tip. For now, from my analysis, am i losing anything else?

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesChaves OK, if you've actually had more Facebook shares than you have had Page Views, then that's a problem. The only non-standard thing I can see in your tracking code is that you refer to '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' when they recommend 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference. It could be an attribution problem; is Google Analytics reporting views elsewhere on your blog (such as the home page) that could be actually on the blog post?

Comment: @J Brazier, since I started the blog, I counted more than 300K pageviews, while GA shows only 66K for the same period. While checking, I found a strange thing: the only two blog posts I've promoted on Facebook are among the top 3 positions with more pageviews on GA, but I have posts with much more than these.

I installed GTM, removed GA tracking code from my website, added Universal Analytics from GTM, and tested with the Tag Assistant for Chrome, which did show me GA was triggered, but after 23 hours, "Triggers" counter still shows zero in the GTM console. Am i losing anything?

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesChaves Did you publish the GTM container?

Comment: @J Brazier, yes i did, tow days ago.

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesChaves Sorry; it's always my first question, as it's very easy to forget to publish your working version of the container. What do you mean that the Triggers counter is 0? If you're looking in Gole Tag Manager, that means 'trigger mechanisms that you have constructed yourself' which is 0 if you have just used the default 'all pages' trigger. Google Tag Manager is just a facilitator; check to see if you'e getting data in Google Analytics.

Comment: @J Brazier, yeah! Now i see the trigger is something I must to configure. I was thinking it was a counter for the tags triggered at each pageview from my website. Now i did configure a pageview trigger. But, can i see a general counter for this trigger, which can help me to check how many pageviews my website gets in order to compare with GA?

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesChaves I'm afraid not. GTM doesn't collect any data whatsoever, it simply deploys your data collection tools.

Comment: @J Brazier, I'm testing Alexa tracking code, and i see the same problem. Alexa shows that just 0,7% was excluded traffic. So, i'm getting something really strange.

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesChaves It sounds like this may be to do with the set up of your website that's leading to either misattribution or loss of data. Do you span multiple domains? Over-use iframes? Have page transitions that don't trigger a page load?

Comment: @J Brazier, i don't use multiple domains nor iframes and page transitions. My website was built with a web MVC framework, so the tracking code is in just one file (the layout template), which is called in every page. I dropped facebook's pixel code, since it is having the same problem as GA. I make use of facebook's, twitter's and g+'s sharing buttons, and they use iframes, is that the case?

Comment: iframes are only a problem if you're trying to get reporting in side of them. Something like a social share button, for example, would be hard to tag up to Gogle Tag Manager. It wouldn't suppress the whole Page View, however. I'm afraid I can't think of any other expantaion, without seeing this is more detail.